# "unmet dependencies", can't remove AOO or LibreOffice

Tags: apache2, libreoffice, dependencies

So, I recently reinstalled Ubuntu (14.04, because 14.10 was giving some minor problems) on my computer.

I forgot about the problems I had last time I installed OpenOffice alongside LibreOffice, and so tried again having both of them on the same machine (I installed OO first, then LO).

Now, Ubuntu can't even update anymore. It gives a problem I've been able to see solved a few times on the web, the infamous "unmet dependencies". The fact is that I already tried `-f install`, and it didn't work, removing either openoffice or libreoffice with `remove`, `purge`, or similar commands doesn't work either, and all of these commands give back the same problem with the dependencies.

I ask for help: how do I remove any one of these programs, possibly without reinstalling Ubuntu again?

I attach the replies I get for each command I've seen on the web that I've tried already:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hyphen-it libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-help-it
  libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-l10n-it
  mythes-en-au mythes-en-us mythes-it
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-crystal libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
  libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 74 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/20,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 79,2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.4.0~rc3-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.4.0~rc3-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.1-9775
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/share/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice/program/’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove ‘/var/lib/libreoffice’: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.4.0~rc3-0ubuntu1~trusty1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt-get autoremove` (Even suggested when I entered last command)

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.4.0~rc3) but it is not installed
 libreoffice-help-en-us : Depends: libreoffice-l10n-en-us
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
 libreoffice-l10n-it : Depends: libreoffice-common but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Seeing as this didn't get me anywhere, I even tried "installing" Lo again, since the problem seems to be cause by its missing packages, but I get the same kind of answer. Same goes for trying autoremove, purge, autoclean, etc.
If anyone needs it, I can post those lines too.

Comment: Would it work to first remove `openoffice-debian-menus`? I notice there is a filename conflict there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to force remove packages installed with unmet dependencies before running `apt-get -f install`. In your specific case, you may try:

```
sudo apt-get -f remove libreoffice-core libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-java-common libreoffice-l10n-en-gb libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-l10n-it
```

Be sure to look at installed packages and add to command above any OpenOffice.org related package, to prevent other conflicts.

Try also to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get check` before trying to run `sudo apt-get install -f`. Hopefully the last command will find nothing to do, and you'll be able to do a clean install with `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`.